# Проблема со считыванием строки с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, строки

Проблема со считыванием строки с консоли. Когда беру строку внутри программы все хорошо, когда пытаюсь считать с консоли(клавиатуры), то считывается только 1 слово и все, короче все до первого пробела. Не могу понять в чем причина. Заранее спасибо за помощь начинаюшему)))

````
#include <string>
//#include <strstream> 
using namespace std;
 
string scramble(string input, int scr){
    auto pos = input.begin();
    auto end = input.end();
    
    while(pos != end)
        //*pos = *pos ^ scr; *pos++;
        *pos++ = *pos ^ scr;
    return input;
}
 
int main(){
    //char mask = 10;
    int mask;
    string inputString;
    //string inputString = "Hello Word";
    cout << " Введите степень:";
    cin >> mask;
    cout << " Введите входное слово: ";
    cin >> inputString;
    string scrambled = scramble(inputString, mask);
    string clear = scramble(scrambled, mask);
    cout<<"Before: " << inputString;
    cout<<"\nAfter: " << scrambled;
    cout<<"\nClear: " << clear;
    
    cout<<"\n";
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `>>`, наподобие

```
cin >> inputString;
```

читает *одно слово*. Для чтения строки есть функция [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), и даже не одна :)